# I am making my blinds automatic, but I don't want to use a delay

Tags: timers

I am trying to make it so I can pull the time so that they open at 8 am and close at 10 pm. The loop is already set up to open and close the blinds completely.

```
#include <CheapStepper.h>

CheapStepper stepper;

boolean moveClockwise = true;
int motorPostion = 10;
boolean up = true;
boolean down = false;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin (9600);
  Serial.println ("Ready to start moving");
}

void loop() {


    for (int i = 1; i < 16384; i++)
      {
      stepper.step (moveClockwise);
      Serial.println (i);
      int nStep = stepper.getStep();
      
      if (nStep%4096==0) {
        Serial.println ("Moved full rotation Clockwise");
        }
     }

    for (int i = 16384; i > 0; i--)
      {
      stepper.step (!moveClockwise);
      Serial.println (i);
      int nStep = stepper.getStep();
      
      if (nStep%4096==0) {
        Serial.println ("Moved full rotation Counter Clockwise");
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: what is your question? ... please format all of your code, not just a part of your code.

Comment: So, are you asking about how to write non-blocking code (Then look at the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example and tutorials about the `millis()` function), or are you asking about how to do things at a specific time of the day (In that case you need an RTC)?